# Limits for inline Query

Tags: soql, limits, governorlimits, inline

I have an account record having name 'POC', This account has 5000 contacts.

Now I am querying in Execute anonymous

1.

```
List<Account> accounts = [Select Id, Name, (Select  Id, Name From Contacts limit 5000) From Account Where Name= 'POC'];
System.debug('Contact Size::' + accounts[0].Contacts.size());
```

I got result in debug 
Contact Size::5000

Now I am modifying query(Adding Description field)

2.

```
  List<Account> accounts = [Select Id, Name, (Select  Id, Name, Description From Contacts limit 5000) From Account Where Name= 'POC'];
            System.debug('Contact Size::' + accounts[0].Contacts.size());
```

Getting an error :

FATAL_ERROR|System.QueryException: Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop

This query is working upto 999 contacts.

Comment: Interesting. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_limits.htm?search_text=subquery) mentions a 1000 record limit...on external objects. Perhaps it applies for some reason to `Contacts` as well? Sounds like a bug, perhaps.

Comment: Are you perhaps using `.size()` on the resultant data: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000002531&language=en_US

Comment: I used .size() in first query and I am not getting any error in first case

Comment: It's a bug : https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000002531&language=en_US

Comment: @AvanishKumar It's not a bug, it's a feature. Returning too much data would cause you to exceed governor limits while processing the query.

Answer (score 2):

Just like the error says, it cannot directly assign the results of the query to the list, use a For loop

```
List<Account> accounts = [Select Id, Name From Account Where Name= 'POC'];
Map<ID,Contact[]> accountToContact = New Map<ID,Contact[]>();

for(Contact c :  [Select  Id, Name, Description, AccountId From Contacts Where AccountID IN :accounts]){

    Contact[] contactList = accountsToContact.get(c.AccountID);
    if(contactList == null) contactList = New Contact[]{};
    contactList.add(c);

    contactMap.put(c.AccountId,contactList);

}
```

Note, the getting of the list from the map has been stated in previous questions to be ideal vs constantly checking map keys etc. [Better way to use Map of List](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/87951/better-way-to-use-map-of-list)

Also, this is a possible duplicate of: [SOQL: How to handle relationship query with more than 50,000 results](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66083/soql-how-to-handle-relationship-query-with-more-than-50-000-results) which may be a good read for you as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use a chunked for loop; this is necessary because of the QueryLocator such a query generates:

```
for(Account aRecord: [SELECT (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account) {
    Integer total = 0;
    for(Contact[] cRecords: aRecord.Contacts) {
        total += cRecords.size();
    }
    System.debug('Total contacts on account '+aRecord.Id+': '+total);
}
```

If all you really want are numbers, you can also use an AggregateResult:

```
for(AggregateResult ar:[SELECT AccountId Id, COUNT(Id) Total FROM Contact GROUP BY AccountId]) {
    System.debug(ar.get('Id')+' has '+ar.get('Total')+' contact(s).');
}
```

Comment: You are right but I just want to know limit, sometimes it working for 5000 and sometimes not working for 999(When including description field) @sfdcfox

Comment: @YogeshGupta The system will choose a limit for you based on the amount of data that can be returned. Using a long text field, for example, will reduce the maximum batch size for a query. There's no way to control what the limit is, or even know what the limit is, which is why you generally should use a for-loop. The logic for how records are queried are abstracted away using standard API mechanisms (QueryLocator/query/queryMore). Generally, if you just want a total, use an aggregate result, otherwise loop over your results.

Comment: I agree with you, Can we query 49999 child contact and 1 parent account, if we are not exceeding the limit of data amount, we are just fetching Id

Comment: @YogeshGupta I don't think that would be possible without a for loop. The system will eventually choose to provide a QueryLocator if there's too many rows/too much estimated data. I would have thought that 2,000 was the maximum, the same as the API maximum batch size, but clearly your code demonstrates that this is not true. Regardless, I don't think it'd be possible to go over 10k rows as an absolute maximum. If I find something, I'll let you know.