# Is it possible to retrieve list of Accounts which has more than 100 contacts associated to it using a single SOQL?

Tags: soql, query, account, contact

Is it possible to retrieve list of Accounts which has more than 100 contacts associated to it using a single SOQL ?

Comment: can you please share what attempt / options you tried so far and highlight where you got issues with your current attempt ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1** 
 You can do this in single soql via :

`Select AccountId from Contact group by AccountId having count(Name) > 100`

**Solution 2**
You have to create a roll-up summary field on account object to count related contacts. Then by this field you can fetch accounts who has more than 100 contacts.

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't possible to make a rollup summary field on `Account` that summarizes `Contact`. However, this could be accomplished with a trigger, or by using Andrew Fawcett's [declarative lookup rollup summary tool](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries). The query is probably the better way to go if this information is only needed in one place.

Answer (score 4):

I think I misinterpreted your initial question. You can filter on aggregations using the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT AccountId, count(Id) records FROM Contact GROUP BY Accountid HAVING count(Id) > 100
```

You should be able to retrieve [at least 999 contacts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138697/limits-for-inline-query/138710#138710) using:

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple query like---
**SELECT Id, Name, 
    ( SELECT Name, Email, BirthDate FROM Contacts )
    FROM Account where Name='Anshul Arora'**

Or you can use LIST in your class to achieve dynamic things  Exp----

List acc= [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account];

System.debug('a' + alist);

List clist = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE Contact.AccountId IN :acc];

System.debug('c' + acc);